# Java AppBundler application pointing to JRE defined by JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, macos, java-7

I have been using [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler/downloads) to pack a Java application as .app. I have managed to run the application if I pack the JRE7 inside of the .app bundle.
Is it possible to  configure .app (in Info.plist) to point to the JRE defined by JAVA_HOME environment variable? 
If I do that, I am getting "Unable to load Java Runtime Environment"! I have tried to configure the JAVA_HOME in different ways, but with no success!

Can anyone provide any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`appbundler` applications can use either an embedded Java 7 JRE inside the app bundle, or the Java 7 JRE installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` (the same one used by the web browser plugin).  They can't use a *JDK* installed under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` (or anywhere else, for that matter) and they definitely can't use Java 6.

What you *can* do, however, is not use `appbundler` and instead build the bundle by hand, with the main executable being a shell script that runs the `java` command line tool from `JAVA_HOME` (maybe falling back to the `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` JRE if `JAVA_HOME` is not set).  Such a script will be able to support both Java 6 and 7.

You would use something like this as `YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PRG=$0

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '^.*-> \(.*\)$' 2>/dev/null`
    if expr "$link" : '^/' 2> /dev/null >/dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
    else
        PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
    fi
done

progdir=`dirname "$PRG"`

if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
elif [ -x /usr/libexec/java_home ]; then
  JAVACMD="`/usr/libexec/java_home`/bin/java"
else
  JAVACMD="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java"
fi

exec "$JAVACMD" -classpath "$progdir/../Resources/Jars/*" \
       -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true \
       my.pkg.MainClass
```

Then put your application's JAR files in `YourApp.app/Contents/Resources/Jars`, the icon in `YourApp.app/Contents/Resources/icon.icns`, and the following in `YourApp.app/Contents/Info.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>YourApp</string><!-- relative to Contents/MacOS -->
        <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
        <string>My clever application</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string>icon.icns</string><!-- relative to Contents/Resources -->
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>YourApp</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

See the [GATE Developer launcher](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/GATE.app/) for full details, though note that this is a slightly more convoluted case as the `.app` script delegates to another script, which in turn loads the JAR files from a location that is outside the `.app` bundle.  The principle remains the same however.

Comment: I have also a shell script to run the app, but that is not an option due to knowledge of users about running scripts. It should be a clickable app. What am I supposed to put in Info.plist of my app under JVMRuntime parameter? How to point it to JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Succeeded to run it with Java installed in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/. Just removed JVMRuntime parameter from Info.plist, instead of setting values pointing to JAVA_HOME!

Comment: @JuricaKrizanic I've put in a bit more detail, including the necessary contents for `Info.plist` to make it work with JAVA_HOME

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts for this good explanation. I extended the basic shell script and released it on GitHub as "universalJavaApplicationStub" ( https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub ). It now supports both Apple Java 6 and Oracle Java 7 and also both Info.plist styles for Java properties in the application bundle (Oracle introduced new property keys). Feel free to use it!

Comment: Note that with macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and higher, you might encounter problems during file access if you launch your App from a script (particularly when using JFileChooser). As already discussed on [this universalJavaApplicationStub project](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub) the script has to be compiled to overcome this issue. You can use a tool like Shell Script Compiler (SHC) to achieve that. Doing so, if trying to access a protected location, you will be prompted a Security Notification and can choose whether to grant access or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8.271.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_271 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

I was facing similar issue, that when I set my java_home as

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

it got set to
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

so I did it like
echo export "JAVA_HOME="Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home" >> ~/.bash_profile

It result's into

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:carot arun$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home

You can also edit it in future if required
go to your user, in my case arun folder
press command + shift + .  to see hidden files
open .bash_profile in any of your favourite editor