# Mac OS X JavaApplicationStub for Java 6 AND Java 7

Tags: java, macos

I am developing a cross platform Java application with native executables. For Mac OS X I use [Jarbundler](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) as an ANT task to create the App package.

Now that Oracle released Java 7 and its own ANT task "[Appbundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler)" I got a problem.

Using the native Mac OS X JavaApplicationStub with Jarbundler only works for Apple Java 6, and using the Oracle JavaApplicationStub with Appbundler only works for Java 7.

I do understand the background of this very well, **but I was wondering whether there is a JavaApplicationStub available that works with both Java 6 and Java 7.**
I haven't found one so far...

*And btw: does the JavaApplicationStub has to be a native C/C++/C# binary? Or could it also be an executable shellscript?*

---

**Update:**

A shell script is a possible alternative to a native JavaApplicationStub.

I extended [Ian Roberts basic shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546508/1128689) and released it on GitHub as ["universalJavaApplicationStub"](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub). It now supports both Apple Java 6 and Oracle Java 7 and also both `Info.plist` styles for Java properties in the application bundle (Oracle introduced new property keys). Feel free to use it!

Comment: Hello ToFi, could you add me to your skype list (my skype is alnasfire) to discuss problems with making java application bundles on linux?

Comment: @alnasfire sorry, I don't know anything about app bundles on Linux. Or do you mean creating Mac App Bundles on Linux?

Comment: yes, I try build my swing application for different platforms (Windows, Unix, MacOS) on Linux. For Mac I want make .app bunldle and put inside jre for working on Mac without installed java. I found your universalJavaAppStub and I want use it, unfortunately default oracle JavaApplicationLauncher doesn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main executable inside a bundle can be a shell script, so you could use a script that first tries `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` (the java 7 JRE install location), and falls back on `/usr/bin/java` if that is not found. The latter will run the most recent JDK that has been installed (6 or 7) and should prompt to install Java 6 if there is *no* JDK found at all.

Comment: Would checking `/usr/libexec/java_home` for a return value be a good way to go? I want to prevent Java 8 Preview to be used and thought about using an installed Java 7 first with `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` then falling back to Java 6 with `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6` and if both don't return anything either display a custom osascript dialog asking the user to install Java 7 or start `/usr/bin/java` to prompt to install Apple Java 6...

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer in @IanRoberts answer to this topic ["Java AppBundler application pointing to JRE defined by JAVA_HOME"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546508/1128689).

He suggests to replace the JavaApplicationStub with a custom shellscript to support both Java 6 and Java 7.