# Creating a Package Install for my Java 7 Application on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, installation

I have an existing Java 6 application that works on a Mac and recently began the switch to use Java 7.

I already made the switch from JarBundler (the old Java 6 utility for creating an application bundle) to Oracle's AppBundler.  This appears to be working as expected.  I can launch the new Java 7 application by double clicking it from the Finder window.  I can even manually move the application "Applications" folder and it also works fine.

When I use the Iceberg utility to create an installer I run into a problem.
The installer is created and works as expected until I look into the Applications folder after running the generated package installer (.pkg).

When I double click on the application nothing happens.  Also it is not picking up the .icns file to display the launch icon (it just display a generic application icon).

I tried comparing all of the files in the Applications Folder to the Application package and they appear to be the same.

I have tried everything I can think of including switching to pkgbuild and productbuild.  These tools had the same behavior as Iceberg.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to hell. Please stay for a while.
I do not know, why Oracle chose not to use the same structure of the old plist.info and Mac App Bundles. There are a lot of problems associated with the new AppBundler (esp. resource path ...). Please have a look at:

- https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub
- [Java AppBundler application pointing to JRE defined by JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546355/java-appbundler-application-pointing-to-jre-defined-by-java-home/17546508#17546508)
- https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler